# How hide AVFoundation debugging logs?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, avfoundation, avplayer

OS X 10.10 and XCode 6.1.1.

Probably I messed up something in the project settings, as now unnecessary logs associated with AVFoundation.framework appears in the console. The first block appears while init, settings and playing music in AVPlayer.

```
[01:08:32.915] FigLimitedDiskCacheProvider_CopyProperty signalled err=-12784 (kFigBaseObjectError_PropertyNotFound) (no such property) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.19/Prototypes/FigByteStreamPrototypes/FigLimitedDiskCacheProvider.c line 947
Jan 14 01:08:32 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Info>: logging starts...
Jan 14 01:08:32 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Debug>: setMessageLoggingBlock: called<
Jan 14 01:08:32 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Debug>: startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Cached 0 enabled backends
Jan 14 01:08:32 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Debug>: setUserInfoDict: enabled backends: ( )
```

These logs appear when I pause or play.

```
Jan 14 01:08:35 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Debug>: sendMessageWithCategory: (null)
Jan 14 01:08:35 MacBook-Air-Roman.local rtcreporting[6668] <Debug>: sendMessageWithCategory: (null)
```

There's also a lot of other notices that I do not need, because all these errors are not critical, and I have never seen them before. I don't understand - how to disable this debug logs? What is it?

Comment: Are you building for Debug or Release?

Comment: I tried both, if we are talking about this window - http://vk320.ru/xcode.png

Comment: @RomanChiller got any solution? why this logs are coming? I am facing same issue

Comment: @pooja-shah unfortunately, no. Just try to ignore this AVFoundation trash. I tested a clean project a couple of lines of code with the AVPlayer - the same thing.

Comment: I think it's trouble of Apple's Xcode 6 because when i created simple empty project with line of AVPlayer or MPAudioPlayer code i have the same logs

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide them unfortunately, the best thing to do if you are analysing the logs is to paste them into notes and get rid of the rubbish by hand before analysing them.